# Json.NET deserializing contents of a JObject?

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

If I have a `JObject`, which contains the property "Fields".
How do I pull out the contents of this property to an `object[]` with deserialized elements?

It seems like no matter what I do, I only get arrays of other JObjects.

```
myJObject["Fields"] {
  "$type": "System.Object[], mscorlib",
  "$values": [
    123,
    "hello"
  ]
}
```

In this case, I want to get an object array containing a long `123` and the string `"hello"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ToObject()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject.htm):

```
        var array = myJObject["Fields"].ToObject<object[]>();

        Debug.Assert(array[0].Equals(123L)); // No assert
        Debug.Assert(array[1].Equals("hello"));  // No assert
```

Comment: Beat me to it! +1 for the quick response :)

Comment: Works like a charm! <3